# IN with LIKE Condition in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to use LIKE inside an IN? The following query produces an error.

```
    Select * 
    from employees
    where salary between 2500 and 10000
    and job_id NOT in (like '%MAN%', like '%CLERK%');
```

What is the correct syntax? I'm using Oracle 11g

Comment: This *in like* thingy is a feature I wanted so many times. Oracle doesn't have such a thing.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger: I don't think any database has something like that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Teradata has support for **LIKE ALL|ANY ('%MAN%','%CLERK%')**. ALL -> ANDed LIKEs, ANY -> ORed LIKEs, you might even use a SELECT to get the search strings

Comment: @dnoeth PostgreSQL has a similar feature with arrays: `LIKE ANY ARRAY ('%MAN%', %CLERK%')`

Comment: You look for `like any (...)` construct which does not work in Oracle but you can mimic it with `exists` and concatenated like expression, see my answer under linked question. (You can look also at the Sokrates` solution at AskTom.)

Answer (score 4):

You can't do both 'like' and 'in' at the time, but you can do this

```
    Select * 
      from employees
     where salary between 2500 
       and 10000
       and job_id NOT like '%MAN%' 
       and job_id NOT like '%CLERK%';
```

Comment: This is what I did after I got an error for the query I mentioned. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no "in like" operator. You could break it up to a series of `LIKE` conditions like @Elfentech suggested, or you could emulate it with the `REGEXP_LIKE` function:

```
SELECT *
FROM   employees
WHERE  salary BETWEEN 2500 AND 10000
AND    NOT REGEXP_LIKE (job_id, '.*[MAN|CLERK].*')
```

Alternatively, you could join on a bunch of `UNION ALL` queries from `dual`:

```
SELECT *
FROM  employees
JOIN  (SELECT 'MAN' AS search FROM dual 
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'CLERK' FROM dual) jobs 
ON    employee.jod_id LIKE CONCAT ('%', jobs.search, '%')
WHERE salary BETWEEN 2500 AND 10000
```

Comment: Thanks for the `REGEXP_LIKE`